# ansible's lvg module isn't idempotent

Tags: ansible

I use following ansible version:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.9.21
  config file = /home/user/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Nov 16 2020, 22:23:17) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
```

a playbook have such task for VG creation:

```
  - name: Create volumes group
    lvg:
     vg: "{{volumes_group_name}}"
     pvs: "{{device}}{{partition_number}}"
     pesize: "4"
```

When I run this playbook for the first time, it creates VG properly, but when I re-run it again it fails on VG creation tasks, though the VG is already there and should do nothing.

```
TASK [Create volumes group] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
Saturday 22 May 2021  20:05:17 +0200 (0:00:01.335)       0:00:03.976 **********
fatal: [192.168.170.110]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "err": "  Can't initialize physical volume \"/dev/sdc1\" of volume group \"CCC_VG01\" without -ff\n  /dev/sdc1: physical volume not initialized.\n", "msg": "Creating physical volume '/dev/sdc1' failed", "rc": 5}
```

I expect it produces no error when VG is created and fine on target system.
Is there any workaround for such behavior?

Comment: I found a workaround using tags in VG creation task and then running playbook with --skip-tags to skip this task